# Conditional tag

Tags: customization

I am using this code to show custom code on single posts.

```
function post_footer() {
if (is_single())
{
?>
<div class="custom">
    <h1><a href="<?php the_field('live_demo'); ?>" target="_blank">Live Demo of <?php the_title(); ?><h1>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_field('download'); ?>" target="_blank">Download<h1>
</div>
<?php
}}
```

How to edit so div should appear only on single post of specified categories, not on all posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a single page: [`is_single()` returns `TRUE`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single).

If a `$post` is in a specific category: [`in_category( $cat )` returns `TRUE`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category). It needs `$cat` as ID, name or (string) slug.

Anyway: [Searching for a list of conditional tags isn´t  that hard.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Codex+conditional+tags)